# using javascript function in url to execute drop down option/button

Tags: javascript, dom-events, html-select

Is it possible to pass values through the url in order to execute a selection from a drop down menu?

For example, if I want to select National League from the drop down menu in [this page](http://rotoworld.com/teams/depth-charts/mlb.aspx) can I reload the new page without clicking on it by passing values through the URL?

From what I can see, when you select National League the javascript function `_doPostBack(....){...}` is called.

Comment: Can you show what `doPostBack()` code is doing. And also please show us how you are handling the code for Language parameter passed as parameter

Answer (score 0):

If you look more closely, `_doPostBack` is called when the `change` event of the `<select>` is fired.

A change event is fired when the value of the element changes. For a `<input type=text>`, this is fired when the text changes and the element loses focus. (Type something and tab out, for example)

For a `<select>` this happens when the selection changes.

If you have

```
<select id="gender">
    <option value="f"> Female </option>
    <option value="m"> Male </option>
    <option value="n"> Prefer not to say </option>
</select>
```

You can attach an event handler for the change event in one of the following ways:

```
<select id="gender" onchange="genderChanged()">
    <option value="f"> Female </option>
    <option value="m"> Male </option>
    <option value="n"> Prefer not to say </option>
</select>
```

OR

in the  part:

```
window.onload = function()
{
   document.getElementById("gender").onchange = genderChanged;
}
```

(jQuery and other javascript frameworks make this lot more simpler)

`genderChanged` is the function (which you write and) which you want to be called when the selection changes.

so, if your `genderChanged` looks like

```
function genderChanged()
{
    var newGender = document.getElementById("gender").value;
    alert("Changed to : "+newGender);
}
```

This value can be submitted to the server, either via traditional form submit (submit the `<form>` that contains the `<select>`), via url or via Ajax.

Comment: thanks for the help guys! i just want the value to be submitted to the server via url. is it possible without writing these javascript functions?

for example can i pass values like this:

http://rotoworld.com/teams/depth-charts/mlb.aspx?&selected="selected"&value="n"

Comment: In the page you have linked, the `form` containing the dropdown is submitted. So you can have something like `<select id="gender" onchange="formName.submit()">` where `formName` is the name of the `<form>`

Comment: I understand.. but can it be done via URL? 

For example..

url.aspx?javascript:formName.submit()?selected="selected"

Comment: @deeby, yes you can submit via url: `onchange="javascript:window.location.href=url.aspx?gender="+this.value+"&someParam=someparamValue"`. But here only the values you explicitly pass in the URL (called query string) will be available to the server (when you submit the form the values of all the elements in the form will be available to the server)

Comment: i basically want to load the MLB rosters for the National League by using the following URL (it's not working though):

[http://rotoworld.com/teams/depth-charts/mlb.aspx?id=cp1_ddlTeams&selected=selected&value=N][1]

unfortunately, it still loads the American League. i haven't figured out which values to pass through the query string..

i think i'm not appending the correct values to the end of the url (i.e. "id=cp1_ddlTeams&selected=selected&value=N")

Comment: this is the source i think is related to loading the National League
"<select name="ctl00$cp1$ddlTeams" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39 ctl00$cp1$ddlTeams\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" id="cp1_ddlTeams">
<option selected="selected" value="A">American League</option>
<option value="N">National League</option>
</select>"


  [1]: http://rotoworld.com/teams/depth-charts/mlb.aspx?id=cp1_ddlTeams&selected=selected&value=N

Comment: @dooby I am sorry, but I am not clear on what you want. Are you trying to et the MLB rosters for the National League in your website by trying to submit to http://rotoworld.com/...? If so this might be more complicated because we don't know what the server is expecting...

Comment: yes, that's exactly what i'm trying to do. is it really complicated even if i know the select,id, and option values? 

also,i've been searching online but i haven't come across anything.. do you know what tags i can search for?

Comment: You have to see what the server is expecting. You can see that, for nstance in the "Net" tab of Chrome's console (or of any browser or Firebug). Right click on the page and select "Inspect Element", and in the sub-window that opens, select the "Network" tab. Now if you submit the request (change in dropdown), you should see a corresponding "Post" request. Click on that and that gives the request parameters submitted to the server. You will have to pass the same parameters. As I told you before, this *is* pretty complicated

Comment: Also, confirm whether what you are trying to do is *correct* - whether the source site is ok with you using the servers to get the data.